# Symfony2 Multiple form Buttons

Tags: symfony

I have an Order Entity. 
I have a Status Entity that contains a number of status options, ie. Submitted, Invoiced, Paid, Shipped (id 1-4). I have a page that I want to list a number of buttons on it each corresponding to a certain status as mentioned above. Basically the reason for the multiple buttons is that I want the user to be able to basically skip certain status records by just clicking the one they want... I have some logic that will determine what buttons to present however my problem is being able to tell what button was clicked when the form is submitted.

From the docs the only way I know to see if a button was clicked is to use:
`$form->get('buttonName')->isClicked();`

The way i am thinking about this right now is that my buttons will be named by the statusId that it corresponds to. ie: `$form->add('status1', SubmitType::class)` # being the ID of the status record.

this problem with this is that the buttons generated on the page will be dynamic. So it would seem like at this point I would need to query my DB for all the statuses and iterate through all the possibilities:

```
foreach ($statuses as $status)
{
    if($form->get('status' . $status->getId())->isClicked()){
    {
        //Do Something

        break;
    }
}
```

I feel like there has to be a better way... IE: `$form->getSubmitButtonName()` which would return "status#" then I could just do a substr() to get the ID out of the name..

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a dropdown menu instead of 4 buttons, and just a simple submit button to save it. It should fix your problem, and look a lot better then having 4 identical buttons that just save different values, example code below:

The Entity should look something like this: (us the toString method to display the actual names instead of (0, 1, 2, 3)

```
abstract class OrderStatus{
 const submitted             = 0;
 const Ivoiced               = 1;
 const Paid                  = 2;
 const Shipped               = 3;
}

 /**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
protected $order_status;  // see OrderStatus enum above

/**
 * Set orderStatus
 *
 * @param integer $orderStatus
 *
 * @return Order
 */
public function setOrderStatus($orderStatus)
{
    $this->order_status = $orderStatus;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get orderStatus
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getOrderStatus()
{
    return $this->order_status;
}

public function getOrderStatusToString()
{
    switch ($this->getOrderStatus()) {
        case 0: return "submitted"; break;
        case 1: return "invoiced"; break;
        case 2: return "paid"; break;
        case 3: return "Shipped"; break;
    }
}
```

add this in the controller:

//the dropdown menu made in form (can be put in a formType instead of controller if you wish)

```
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder(your.entity.name)
        ->add('orderStatus', 'choice', array(
            'choices'  => array(
                'submitted' => 0,
                'invoiced' => 1,
                'paid' => 2,
                'Shipped' => 3,
            ),
            'choices_as_values' => true,
            'label'=>false
        ))

    $form->add('save', 'submit', array('label' => 'Save'));
    $form = $form->getForm();

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist(your.entity.name);
        $em->flush();
   }
```

in your html file smth like: (with any css you want)

```
        {{ form_start(form) }}
        {{ form_widget(form) }}
        {{ form_end(form) }}
```

This all together (with some tweaks) should do the trick

Comment: So, I was debating this also myself, however it seems to have opened another can of worms... My status is an entity in my database, that has a self referencing many to many relationship which defines what statuses are allowed to be next. So I am trying to add an EntityType form field for status rather than a choice type, the problem is I need to create a query builder to limit the entities to just the ones in the self referencing relationship and I am stuck... Previously I could just use $status->getNextStatues() but when I need to give a querybuilder i am stuck...

Comment: Asked a new question over here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39661800/many-to-many-self-referencing-query-builder
I'll probably mark yours as the answer once I get everything fully working. Thanks, hopefully you can help with the other part