# Many to Many Self Referencing Query_builder

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have an entity called Status that has a self referencing many to many relationship to define what each statuses next available status is:

```
class Status
{
    private $id;

    //...

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Status", mappedBy="nextStatuses")
     */
    private $previousStatuses;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Status", inversedBy="previousStatuses")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="status_mapping",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="status_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="next_status_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     *      )
     */
    private $nextStatuses;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="OrderStatus", mappedBy="status")
     * @ORM\OrderBy({"createdTime" = "ASC"})
     */
    private $orderStatuses;

    //...    

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->nextStatuses = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->previousStatuses = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    //...
}
```

I am creating a form type and need to add the status entity as a field and limit its choices to `$nextStatuses` the problem is the EntityType requires a query_builder and I cant simply say `$status->getNextStatuses()`

What I currently have (and have had a few variations of it none of which worked):

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        //Current status passed as option
        $status = $options['status'];
        $builder->add('status', EntityType::class, array(
            'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Status',
            'query_builder' => function (StatusRepository $er) use ($status) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('s')
                    ->leftJoin('s.previousStatuses', 'ps')
                    ->where('s.previousStatuses = :status')
                    ->setParameter('status', $status);
            },));

}
```

above query results in the error `[Semantical Error] line 0, col 80 near 'previousStatuses': Error: Invalid PathExpression. StateFieldPathExpression or SingleValuedAssociationField expected.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `previousStatuses` association is a `ArrayCollection` so for Doctrine this statement is wrong:

```
->where('s.previousStatuses = :status')
```

Use the `ps` alias in `where` clausule, something like this:

```
//...
return $er->createQueryBuilder('s')
   ->leftJoin('s.previousStatuses', 'ps')
   ->where('ps.id = :status') // <---- here
   ->setParameter('status', $status);
```

I suppose the `status` field for `Status` entity, but this could be `name` or any other, checks this in your entity.

Comment: I'm confused....
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 78 near 'status = :st': Error: Class AppBundle\Entity\Status has no field or association named status...

status is the name of the entity, would I need to query on statusId perhaps? I'm very confused...

Comment: I don't know what is the property name that you need to compare exactly,  the question is what is the possible `$status` value ? which is the property name from your entity that matching with it?

Comment: well, in plain english I am saying: Find all status records that have a previousStatus of $status... Meaning, what are my possible next statuses...

The join table basically maps statuses to possible next statuses

Comment: well, if you `$status` is an instance of `Status` then simply use `where('ps.id = :status')` I just update my answer with that.